# JAVA SOCKS: authentication failed while using command-line arugments

Tags: java, authentication, proxy, socks

I'm trying to get the JVM to run through my socks proxy. I have set it up, and tested it through proxifier, it is fully functional. When I add the argument:

-DsocksProxyHost=my.socks.proxy.ip

I get an authentication failed, the proxy is set up on port 1080, which is default, I'm not sure what's going on. I have disabled all authentication on the proxy, and I'll restate, it works through proxifier.